# Will Wait Activity in a journey affect the entry schedule?

Tags: journeybuilder

I'm creating a journey to send survey emails by using Journey Builder in Marketing Cloud.

I use an automation (SQL Query) as entry event and this automation starts daily at 8 AM. The users who already go the survey can be re-injected into the journey only after 90 days. So I think to meet this requirement of 90-days "freeze time" I can simply setup a Wait Activity as the last step of the journey (before Exit), right?

I don't quite know if the Wait Activity in a journey would affect the entry schedule? The automation  should start daily at 8 AM so that new users will be injected into the journey daily, if this journey has a Wait Activity of 90 days, could it happen that the journey will also wait for 90 days and then handle the new user?

Sorry for the silly question, I'll be glad if someone could help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you have it set up to have users enter only after exiting, and the DE you are pulling from as an entry source has re-injected them, I would think that would be fine. I am no expert, but the logic makes sense.

Will the persons exiting the journey be called again to enter exactly 90 days after? If they enter the DE any sooner than that, they would be rejected because they have not yet exited, no?

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Hello Adri_Z, thanks a lot for your kind answer!

Yes, the users can only take the journey again after exactly 90 days. It they will enter the Data Extension earlier than 90 days, they should be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

@Xing
A bit late for the party, but here's the answer for future readers:

- While a contact waits on Journey Builder Wait Activity, the Journey still admits new contacts.
- Set the setting for Contacts to Enter only After Exit.
- Make sure that your Wait Activity is in ***Journey Builder***, as the last Activity in the journey, and not as an 'Automation Studio' Wait Activity.
- Substract any waiting times within the Journey to reach exactly 90 days (e.g. If your journey is Send Email1 > Wait 2 Days > Send Email2 > Exit , your final results should be:

Send Email1 > Wait 2 Days > Send Email2 > Wait 88 days > Exit

Hope this helps !